# How can I authorize the Bing Translate API on localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure, authentication, translate

How can I authenticate the Microsoft translate API and gt it working on my localhost ?

I have attempted to use my microsoft **primary key** and **client_id** to no avail. I really have no clue. Help!!
**note: ** the client.setRequestHeader() method below.

Thanks in advance.

function _translate(text, to, from){
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

```
        var API = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/translate?" +
            "Text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) +
            "&To=" + encodeURIComponent(to) +
            "&From=" + encodeURIComponent(from);

        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

        client.open('POST', API, true);

        client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + 'what-goes-here-exactly??');

        client.onload = function(){
            if (client.status >= 200 && client.status > 300){
                resolve(client.responseText);
            }else{
                reject(client.response);
            }
        };

        client.error = function(){
            reject(client.response);
        };

        client.send();
    });

    return promise;
}

_translate("I love pizza", 'en', 'es')
    .then(function(translation){
        alert(translation);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512387.aspx) you would set the header as follows:

```
client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + your_access_key);
```

You obtain your access token by following [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx), in short:

1. Subscribe to the Microsoft Translator API on Azure Marketplace
2. Register your application Azure DataMarket
3. Make an HTTP POST request to the token service